# Do I have to use Visual Studio preview in order to use MAUI?

Tags: .net, maui

I'm currently using 17.4.0 preview 1, I'm using it to create MAUI apps.
Currently, is still mandatory to use the preview? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Visual Studio 17.3, you can now use the stable version to use .NET MAUI. Make sure to check the workload during the Visual Studio installation.

Of course, you can also still use the Visual Studio preview version or you can even use them side-by-side.